# MYSQL reference to another table fields

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get for a specific period of time the quantity of products sold. For this example : the products table has a quantity field which increments whenever a certain product is sold. The orders table has a start date and end date. Is there a way i can hold a reference of the products table (like an object) in my orders table so i can see the quantity sold for each product every start - end date ? A quick example : I am having 2 products:
`1 bike 25000 3` and `2 sportbike 30000 5` sold for my date. So an order would be something like : `1 05.07.2015 05.07.2015` and those products.

```
CREATE TABLE products (
    product_no integer PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(20),
    price float,
    quantity integer,
);

CREATE TABLE sells (
    sell_id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    start_date date,
    end_date date    
);
```

//New idea :

```
CREATE TABLE products (
        product_no integer PRIMARY KEY,
        name varchar(20),
        price float
    );

CREATE TABLE sells (
        sell_id integer PRIMARY KEY,
        date date,
        quantity integer,
        product_id integer FOREIGN KEY 
    );
```

Comment: You mean like an `OrderLines` table that contains an `order_id`, a `product_no`, a `quantity` and maybe a `price`? That table can hold the products sold per order, and then you can query which products were sold on which dates. I don't really get the start date and end date though. I'd think an order for products has just a single date.

Comment: Yes. The point for those dates is that i need to see how many of x and y products have been sold each day. If you can give me a better idea how to do that, i would appreciate it.

Comment: I think I just did. :) To me, an Order is a single moment at which you order products, containing a date and possibly a reference to a customer. The OrderLine contains links between that order and a product. An order can have multiple OrderLines if a customer orders multiple products. To get the products sold on a day, write a query that gets all orders for that day (or all orders within a date range), and join the orders on their order lines so you can sum per product. I'd add this in an answer, but I'm just hinting towards a solution now, because I'm not sure I understand the question fully.

Comment: I think you understood it. I need to know what products have been sold each and the amount for each of them. Please post an answer :)

Comment: I think you need to describe what prod.qty means and you need the OrderLines table desc by @GolezTrol otherwise this doesnt make sense. Orders makes no sense

Comment: I got a new idea, check my edit . The only thing is that i will get my table populated really quick . Basically i will have a new entry whenever a product is sold , with the date , the products id and the quantity sold. I can do this or either create a table for each day with the products sold . Which is better ?

Comment: I will look and maybe propose 3 tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless an order is always for a single product, I think you will need a third table. To me a minimal *) data model for this situation would look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE products (
    product_no integer PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(20) not null,
    price float,
    quantity_on_stock integer not null
);

CREATE TABLE orders (
    order_id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    order_date date not null
);

CREATE TABLE orderlines (
    order_id integer not null REFERENCES orders.order_id,
    product_no integer  REFERENCES products.product_no,
    price integer,
    quantity integer not null,
    PRIMARY KEY(order_id, product_no)
);
```

Then, a query to get sales in a certain period could look like this:

```
select
  p.product_no,
  p.name,
  sum(ol.quantity)
from
  products p
  inner join orderlines ol on ol.product_no = p.product_no
  inner join orderlines o on o.order_id = ol.order_id
where
  ol.order_date between :start_date and :end_date
```

*) I say minimal, but it's actually less than minimal. You'd probably want to store invoices too, or at least some kind of indication that says whether an order is actually payed for and delivered, since sometimes orders are cancelled, or are just waiting open.

Comment: I dont know what inner join does, as i am new to mysql . But isn't my last comment the same as here ?  with the last part you wrote ?

Comment: Another question is , will it take a long time to give me the total quantity sold for a day if that day is actually at the bottom of the table and i have like 100k lines in it ? how can i prevent that ?

Comment: There is a difference between tables, in which you actually store the data a structured as possible (and with as less redundancy as possible), and queries that can combine table data into a form you may need at a particular time. So to get total product sales, you can read the individual sales from orders and order lines using a query that sums them, for instance, into a total per product. That query result is calculated based on the table date, but it itself is not table data and is not stored in the database.

Comment: You can speed up those queries using indexes on the table, but that's a completely different story. It's better to follow some tutorials and get back if you have specific implementation questions.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely want a `sales` table showing what was sold and when, rather than a table showing the running inventory.

It is *much* easier in SQL to aggregate detail to create running totals than it is to reconstruct detail from running totals.

So, if you happen to have a `sales` table containing, among other things, columns for `product_id`, `quantity`, and `ts` (the timestamp of the sale), then you can get a summary of sales by `product_id` and sales date like this.

```
SELECT product_id,
       DATE(ts) AS salesdate,
       SUM(quantity) AS quantity
  FROM sales
 WHERE ts >= :start_date
   AND ts < :end_date + INTERVAL 1 DAY
 GROUP BY DATE(ts), product_id
```

One of the things that's cool about this is you can add a column for `transaction_type` to this table. If a customer returns a product you tag it `return` and use a negative quantity.  If your shop receives a shipment of products you tag it `restock` and use a negative quantity.  Then, if you want to show net sales -- sales less returned products -- it's a small change to the query.

```
SELECT product_id,
       DATE(ts) AS salesdate,
       SUM(quantity) AS quantity
  FROM sales
 WHERE ts >= :start_date
   AND ts < :end_date + INTERVAL 1 DAY
   AND transaction_type IN ('sale', 'return')
 GROUP BY DATE(ts), product_id
```

If you want to know how much stock you had on on hand for each product for a particular end_date, you do this (starting from the beginning of time).

```
SELECT product_id,
       SUM(quantity) AS quantity
  FROM sales
 GROUP BY product_id
```

In actual inventory / sale systems, it's common to take inventory once a year, close out the previous year's sales table, and start a new one with a starting value for each product. it's also common to organize sales by `sales_order` and `sales_detail`, so you can track the sale of multiple items in each transaction.